# Is this tag bad [form] for this site?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

Quoting the Tag-Wiki:

> An HTML form is a section of a document containing normal content,
>   markup, special elements called controls (checkboxes, radio buttons,
>   menus, etc.), and labels on those controls.
>
> Users generally "complete" a form by modifying its controls (entering
>   text, selecting menu items, etc.), before submitting the form to an
>   agent for processing (e.g., to a Web server, to a mail server, etc.)

I find asking myself: What context does this provide in a question? What benefit does that tag have?

Does it imply something that [html](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html) doesn't?

In short: Why do we have that tag?

Comment: For me this actually raises the question of whether or not [tag:form] is too specific as is. What about WinForms? Or UserForms? (Sorry, MS guy. They're the only examples I can think of off the top of my head.) Do we really need specific tags for all of these things? If so, fine. But then [tag:form] should probably be replaced with [tag:html-form].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, [form](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form) should stay.

[html](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html) is a general form of web-based user interface which focuses on output from the system, and display to the user.

[form](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form) focuses on user input, it is a specific subset of HTML that has a dedicated purpose that's distinctly different from other uses of HTML